# JavaScript loop issue in iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

English isn’t my first language, so please **forgive any mistakes**.

**FCIM :** I'm using iMacros v9.0.3 on Firefox 53.0.3 (64 bit) in Windows 8 x64

I'm trying to loop the JavaScript code in iMacros with a `Datasource`.

It's working fine when it's just iim (iMacro) code.
It perfectly enters the right value in the right row number.
But after I convert the script from iim into JavaScript, it doesn't enter the data correctly.

**for eg**, in iMacro code when I loop, it rightly enters row by row data:

- loop1 - kannan1

  loop2 - kannan2

  loop3 - kannan3 ...

But after I convert it into **JavaScript**, it always enters **THE SAME DATA** over and over again.

- loop1 - kannan1

  loop2 - kannan1

  loop3 - kannan1 ...

Here is my **Datasource** [demo.csv](http://www.pastebin.com/dl/BfGj4YcG]demo.csv)

**Here is an iim code example**

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE demo.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 8
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !LOOP 1
URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/AutoDataEntry
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:fname CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:lname CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:address CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:city CONTENT={{!COL4}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:zip CONTENT={{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:state CONTENT=%IN
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:country CONTENT=%73
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:email CONTENT={{!COL8}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:demo ATTR=TXT:Submit
```

**Here is a Javascript example code**

```
var macro; 
macro =  "CODE:";
for(var X = 1; X <= 10; X++){

  macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
  macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE demo.csv" + "\n";
  macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 8" + "\n";
  macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} " + "\n";
  macro +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"
  macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/AutoDataEntry" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:fname CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:lname CONTENT={{!COL2}}" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:address CONTENT={{!COL3}}" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:city CONTENT={{!COL4}}" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:zip CONTENT={{!COL5}}" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:state CONTENT=%IN" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:country CONTENT=%73" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo ATTR=ID:email CONTENT={{!COL8}}" + "\n";
  macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:demo ATTR=TXT:Submit" + "\n";
  iimPlay(macro)

}
iimPlay(macro)
```

Any ideas on how to make it loop correctly? and thx in advance to all my brothers  :)

Comment: I improved your English and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

### Background

- User PayovYuxug wishes to run auto-generated code which has auto-generated regions that are generated by a loop.

### Problem

- The auto-generated code behaves differently than when simply entered by hand without auto-generation.

### Solution

- Compare the auto-generated code, and determine whether the loop-generated-region includes any unintentionally repeated commands that should only appear once.

### Simple example

The following is a simple example demonstrating the issue in pseudo-code

#### Hand-edited source code

```
## Code
connection = new DatabaseConnection;
print connection.currentrow.firstname;
print connection.currentrow.lastname;
print connection.currentrow.age;
connection.getNextRow();

## Result
Alice Anderson 33
```

#### Generated source code

```
## Code
mycode = "";
for ixx in range(0 .. 3):
   mycode += "connection = new DatabaseConnection;"  //<--MISTAKE
   mycode += "print connection.currentrow.firstname;"
   mycode += "print connection.currentrow.lastname;"
   mycode += "print connection.currentrow.age;"
   mycode += "connection.getNextRow();"
myApp.run(mycode);
```

#### Results from generated source code

```
## Actual Result
Alice Anderson 33
Alice Anderson 33
Alice Anderson 33
Alice Anderson 33

## Desired Result
Alice Anderson 33
Bob Banderson 44
Charlie Chanderson 55
Danny Danderson 66

## BROKEN ;; Actual Result does not match desired result, because
## the DatabaseConnection gets reset every time.
```

#### Fixing the mistake

```
## Fixed code
mycode = "";
mycode += "connection = new DatabaseConnection;"  //<-- FIXED MISTAKE
for ixx in range(0 .. 3):
   mycode += "print connection.currentrow.firstname;"
   mycode += "print connection.currentrow.lastname;"
   mycode += "print connection.currentrow.age;"
   mycode += "connection.getNextRow();"
myApp.run(mycode);
```

### Case-specific example

The same mistake seems to be repeated here. These lines should not be inside the loop.

```
SET !DATASOURCE demo.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 8
```

### Pitfalls

- For this specific question, there is no need to generate code with JavaScript, because iim already handles iteration over the rows in the data source anyway. Why is there a need to generate code at all?

Comment: I did Just like what you said, but nothing changed :( anyway thanks for your valuable reply bro :)

Comment: @kannankr why are you generating the code with JavaScript anyway? you don't need to do that with SET !DATASOURCE demo.csv

Comment: bcoz i want to protect my code **(obfuscate)** so no one change/edit them :)